# distinguish between viewcontrollers of didSelectViewController

Tags: objective-c

What do I need to replace ??? with to make it work? Thanks!

```
- (void) tabBarController: (UITabBarController *) tabBarController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController {
switch(viewController.???) {
    case 0:
        // first UIViewController was selected
    case 1:
        // second UIViewController was selected
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you doing this ? The view controllers would be selected automatically when you click the correct tab, that is assigned to its corresponding view.

Answer (score 1):

You have this a bit confused.

In

`(void) tabBarController: (UITabBarController *) tabBarController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController {`

the viewcontroller selected is pointed to by the pointer `viewController`.

Notice how it says `didSelectViewController: viewController`, this is a common syntax in Objective C which indicates that the UIViewController object that was selected is pointed to by the pointer that statement.  In other languages one only has to mention the type of the object coming in, in Objective C the reason for that object is part of the method name.

There is no need for a switch, nor would one work.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(tabBarController.selectedIndex){
    case 0:
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to check which viewController was selected is to check out the tag which is an NSInteger property of a UIView.

So you can do...

```
switch(viewController.view.tag)
{
    case 0:
        // do work
        break;
    case 1:
        // do work
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this line of code:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

You can check this number to know the tab selected, hence the controller selected.